# Are SQLAlchemy MetaData objects serializable?

Tags: python, serialization, sqlalchemy

In my application, I have multiple processes that run `MetaData.reflect` against some large DB, which takes a while. Is there a way to serialize and store the results of reflection so that I can simply load `MetaData` from a file instead of generating it each time?

Tried to `pickle` them, which didn't work.

Comment: Pickling worked for me - can you elaborate?

Comment: @snakecharmerb: last time I checked it contained references to Connection (or Engine), which wasn't serializable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previous versions of SQLAlchemy supported passing an engine to `MetaData'`s constructor, but this is [no longer supported in SQLAlchemy 2.0](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/migration_20.html#implicit-and-connectionless-execution-bound-metadata-removed). Consequently, [MetaData](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData) instances can be serialised with the [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module.

```py
import pickle
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite://')
with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute(sa.text("""CREATE TABLE t (id int)"""))

metadata = sa.MetaData()
metadata.reflect(engine)

bs = pickle.dumps(metadata)

metadata2 = pickle.loads(bs)
print(f'{metadata2.tables=}')
```

Output (formatted for readability):

```
metadata2.tables=FacadeDict(
    {'t': Table('t', MetaData(), Column('id', INTEGER(), table=<t>), schema=None)}
)
```